# Gnome desktop blacked out after reboot and logon

Tags: 16.04, gnome

After successfully passing the password on the logon window, desktop blacks out. I can tell the monitor is powered. It just shows black. Having tried rebooting multiple times, I saw often that the background image of the desktop appeared but only briefly then the display blacked out.

K/b input seems to be working as I can tell my cursor is moving (confirmed that cursor moved to an external computer via [synergy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that after the following, the issue is resolved. Not sure why, and not even sure where to report this.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-utils 
$ sudo reboot
```

Versions

```
$ apt-cache policy virtualbox-guest-utils
virtualbox-guest-utils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1
$ uname -a
Linux 130s-p50 4.10.0-40-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 15:37:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.18.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me on 20.04 What finally worked for me was to install GNOME Tweaks from Ubuntu Software and turn themes on and off.

It took me weeks of trying everything else to get there...